How to get all columns from one table and few column from another using LINQ?
SELECT 
    p.Id, p.Item, h.Date,h.Shop,
    SUM(h.Harvested) AS Harvested 
FROM 
    Plantings p 
LEFT JOIN 
    Harvests h ON p.Id = h.Id
GROUP By p.Id, p.Item, h.Date, h.Shop

This code is used to select all columns from the Plantings table and few column (i.e. total sum of Harvested and Date) from Harvests table.
My requirement is to rewrite this code using LINQ method.
Plantings table



Id
Item
Planted




3
Carrot
2.00


4
Apple
1.00



Harvests table



HId
Item
Harvested
Id
Date
Shop




1
Carrot
10.00
3
4/09/2024
4


2
Apple
20.00
4
9/09/2024
11


3
Carrot
5.00
3
4/09/2024
4


4
Carrot

3
7/09/2024
2



This is what I have tried
IEnumerable DataSource = (from p in _context.Plantings 
                          join h in _context.Harvests on p.Id equals h.Id 
                          select t1).ToList();

Expected output table



Id
Item
Harvested




3
Carrot
15.00


4
Apple
20.00


3
Carrot





Possible duplicate. Just curious: why? Isn't LINQ usually used when you don't already know the SQL you'd need?

Does your SQL query really execute? I'd expect an error.

@Jarth no error, it's executing perfectly

@jarlh MySQL allows this misfeature, where you don't need to specify GROUP BY columns, as long as you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY setting off. I suspect OP isn't actually using SQL Server.

You can just create an object with a subquery in your LINQ.
var data = (
    from p in _context.Plantings 
    select new {
        p,
        Harvested = _context.Harvests.Where(h => h.Id == p.Id).Sum(h => h.Harvested),
    }
).ToList();

Normally you would have some kind of foreign-key relationship, then you can just do
var data = (
    from p in _context.Plantings 
    select new {
        p,
        Harvested = p.Harvests.Sum(h => h.Harvested),
    }
).ToList();


thank you for your feedback. I am getting this error 'invalid expression term select'. The error is coming from the on select

with the first part of your answer, only Harvested column is populating data, but the rest of the columns are showing nothing

Not sure why that should be, it's no different than selecting from Plantings directly. What are you using to see the columns, are you checking in the debugger?

the problem is that Your code is omitting rows that have no value in Harvested column from Harvests table

Again, that's not possible if you use the subquery like I showed, because the result should just be 0 for that column. You are going to have to give a [mcve] to show how that's happening. Maybe create another question.

Since your plantings table and harvested table is a one-to-many mapping based on Id. so you will need join...into for this.
Class definitions:
public class Planting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public double Planted { get; set; }
}

public class Harvest
{
    public int HId { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public double? Harvested { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Shop { get; set; }
}

Linq join:
    var Plantings = new List<Planting>
    {
        new Planting {Id = 3, Item = "Carrot", Planted = 2.0},
        new Planting {Id = 4, Item = "Apple", Planted = 1.0}
    };
    var Harvests = new List<Harvest>
    {
        new Harvest {HId = 1, Item = "Carrot", Harvested = 10.0, Id = 3, Date = new DateTime(2024, 9, 4), Shop = 4},
        new Harvest {HId = 2, Item = "Apple", Harvested = 20.0, Id = 4, Date = new DateTime(2024, 9, 9), Shop = 11},
        new Harvest {HId = 3, Item = "Carrot", Harvested = 5.0, Id = 3, Date = new DateTime(2024, 9, 4), Shop = 4},
        new Harvest {HId = 4, Item = "Carrot", Harvested = null, Id = 3, Date = new DateTime(2024, 9, 7), Shop = 2}
    };
    
    // assuming Id in Plantings are distinct
    var joined = (from planting in Plantings
            join groupedHarvests in Harvests.GroupBy(q => new {q.Id, q.Item, q.Date, q.Shop}) on planting.Id equals groupedHarvests.Key.Id into
                harvestsForPlanting
            select harvestsForPlanting.Select(g => new
            {
                planted = planting.Planted, id = g.Key.Id, item = g.Key.Item, shop = g.Key.Shop, date = g.Key.Date,
                harvested = g.Sum(r => r.Harvested ?? 0.0)
            }))
        .SelectMany(q => q);

Results:


thank you for your feedback. The problem with your code is that the rows that have no value in Harvested column from Harvests table are not showing in the output table. I want them to be displayed too.

I saw you updated your expected result table. Why do you even need Plantings table? because it seems to me you just need to group the Harvest table by Id, Item, Date, Shop, and them sum "Harvested" column in each group?

@Milie24, I updated the code. I added "Planted" in the results too, because that is the only reason I can think of for doing a left join on Plantings table and Harvested table.

var result = _context.Plantings
.GroupJoin(
    _context.Harvests,
    planting => planting.Id,
    harvest => harvest.Id,
    (planting, harvests) => new
    {
        planting.Id,
        planting.Item,
        Harvested = harvests.Sum(h => (decimal?)h.Harvested) ?? 0
    }
).ToList();

Explanation:

GroupJoin method: is used to allow left join between _context.Plantings & _context.Harvests
Sum(h => (decimal?)h.Harvested) ?? 0: based on the left join there will be null values, so convert the summation of null to 0


I am getting the below error when l tried your code System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet
.GroupJoin(
outer: DbSet,
inner: planting => (Nullable)planting.Id,

So you have two tables, Plantingsand Harvests. There is a one-to-many relation between these two tables. Every Planting has zero or more Harvests, every Harvest is the harvest of exactly one Planting, namely the PLanting that the foreign key Harvest.Id refers to.
You'll have classes similar to the following. (Tip: consider to give us these classes next time you ask a question).
class Planting
{
    public int Id {get; set;}            // primary key
    public string Item {get; set;}       // what crop has been planted on this Planting
    public decimal Planted {get; set;}   // the amount of planted crops
}

class Harvest
{
    public int Hid {get; set;}           // primary key
    public string Item {get; set;}       // what crop has been Harvested?
    public decimal Harvested {get; set;} // the amount of harvested crops

    // This Harvest was done on exactly one Planing, nameley the Planting
    // that the foreign key refers to:
    public int Id {get; set;}            // foreign key to Planting
}

And your DbContext:
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Planting> Plantings {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Harvest> Harvests {get; set;}
}

By the way, did you notice that your database doesn't have the first normal form? Using this table layout, you could Harvest Apples on a Planting that contains only Carrots. Or is this a scenario you want to consider?
Advice: Your foreign key has a confusing identifier. Consider changing the name Id to PlantingId. Reserver the name Id only for primary keys. This will help readers of your code to understand what the properties mean.

Requirement: give me the Id and Item of all Plantings, each with the total of harvested items on that Planting

...even if you harvested Apples on a Planting that has only Carrots. But hey, that's what your SQL command does.
Whenever you have a one-to-many relation, and you need to fetch "properties of items with some values from their related sub-items", consider to use one of the overloads of Queryable.GroupJoin. If you need to fetch "properties of items, each with some properties of the item they belong to" consider to use one of the overloads of Queryable.Join.
As you want "Plantings with some information of their related subitem Harvests", we need to use GroupJoin. I almost always use the overload that has a parameter resultSelector. This enables us to specify exactly what we want.
// GroupJoin Plantings with Harvests:
var plantingsWithTotalHarvested = dbContext.Plantings.GroupJoin(
    dbContext.Harvests,
    planting => planting.Id,      // from every Planting take the primary key
    harvest => harvest.Id,        // from every Harvest take the foreign key to
                                  // the Planting it belongs to.

    // parameter resultSelector: take every planting,
    // each with its zero or more Harvest to create one new
    (planting, harvestsOfThisPlanting) => new
    {
        Id = planting.Id,
        Item = planting.Item,

        Harvested = harvestsOfThisPlanting.Select(harvest => harvest.Harvested)
                                          .Sum(),
    });

In words: take the tables of Plantings and Harvest. From Every Planting in the table find all Harvests belonging to this Planting. From every Planting, take the values of properties Id and Item. From each Harvest belonging to this Planting take the value of property Harvested and sum them. Put the result in property Harvested.

The following will help you to achieve what you want:
var finalResult = (from h in  _context.Harvests         
    join p in  _context.Plantings on h.Id equals p.Id
    group h by new { p.Id, p.Item } into g
    select new
    {
        Id = g.Key.Id,
        Item = g.Key.Item,
        Harvested = g.Sum(m => m.Harvested)
    }).ToList();

which is equivalent to
var finalResult =  _context.Harvests.Join( _context.Plantings, h => h.Id, p => p.Id, (h, p) => (h,p))
                        .GroupBy(g => new { g.h.Id, g.h.Item }).Select(f => new
                        {
                            Id = f.Key.Id, Item = f.Key.Item, Harvested = f.Sum(d => d.h.Harvested)
                        });


@Sam I am getting this error 'Plantings is a type which is not valid in the given context'

Good point @Charlieface. I removed ToList() as its unnecessary there.

@Milie24 I updated my answer. Please check now.

thank you for your feedback. I have tried the first part of your codes which  is returning data as INNER JOIN method, but my requirement is to return record based on LEFT JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN. I prefer the LEFT OUTER JOIN as my solution. Please assist me.

@Milie24, both the options are doing LEFT JOIN first followed by grouping as you need total count of Harvested. Both of the above queries return your expected output. Could you edit your question or elaborate on what exactly you are expecting.
